# "Должны" или "должно"?

Tags: род, число

В отчете обязательно **должны** быть представлены утвержденное техническое задание или программа работ с приведением основания для их проведения

Comment: В отчете должно быть представлено техническое задание или программа работ с обязательной аргументацией.

Comment: "Должны" и тд обычно используется когда кто-то должен или что-то должно, а не должно быть то-то, должно быть - это формулировка, которая ставит проблему, но не формулирует возможности её выполнения: Карфаген должен быть разрушен. Должно быть то или сё в деловом языке выглядит как авторитарный приказ, и звучать резко и грубо. Поэтому лучше переформулировать: в отчёте необходимо предоставить утверждённое техническое задание или программа работ с обязательной аргументацией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сказуемое следует ставить во множественном числе. **В отчете обязательно должны быть представлены утвержденное техническое задание или программа работ с приведением основания для их проведения.** Если есть однородные подлежащие и главные члены предложения стоят в обратном порядке, чаще используется единственное число; также при использовании разделительного союза предпочтительнее единственное число сказуемого. Однако у нас подлежащие имеют разный грамматический род, поэтому стоит предпочесть множественное число. Информация из статьи Розенталя и Теленковой "Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим".